# How to select rows from two tables that differ in one field?

Tags: mysql, database

Sorry for the entry-level database question but I really want to learn this.

I have two tables customer_change and customer_full and I want to select rows from customer_full that same customer(same customer_id) but with different customer_points.

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer_change a,customer_full b 
WHERE 
    a.ID = b.ID AND 
    a.CUSTOMER_POINTS ！= b.CUSTOMER_POINTS
```

Now it works. But it will return rows in both tables, how could I change the query to only return the rows in the second table?

Also, the returned rows may contain two rows that have the same IDs, could I modify my query to only include the first row that has this ID?

Could experts offer some help? Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful if you posted the error message.

Comment: Curious, what's up with your exclamation mark? It looks special, which could just be this site, but if it is a special character, mysql might not recognize it. You can try `<>` instead of `!=` if that's the case.

Comment: @all, thanks. It is actually the ! has the problem, since it is in another character set. MySql maybe doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL inequality operator is `<>`, not `!=`. *(Apologies: I note that `!=` is supported in at least some implementations! As the comments on the question have pointed out, it seems to be a character set problem. I stand by the rest of my answer, though. :))*

That said, I recommend [learning about JOIN syntax](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html), rather than joining tables using WHERE criteria. The former lends itself to more-readable queries, and lets you exercise finer control over how the tables are joined.

For example, your query above would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer_change a
JOIN customer_full b ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.CUSTOMER_POINTS <> b.CUSTOMER_POINTS
```

Comment: MySQL does allows either `!=` or `<>`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal (+1 for correction edit).

Comment: `<>` and `!=` are the same things in MySQL... (+1 for correction edit too)

Comment: And in SQL Server, I've just found out. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `*` will select everything which results from the cross product of all tables in your query. You can "select" specific columns by giving their name in the `SELECT` clause such as:

```
SELECT customer_points 
FROM customer_change
```

Or you can select only columns from a specific table (or multiple tables) by adding the table name to the beginning of the column name followed by a period. Such as:

```
SELECT customer_change.customer_points, customer_full.ID
FROM customer_change, customer_full
```

In your case, you can select ONLY the records in the second table:

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM customer_change a,customer_full b 
WHERE 
    a.ID = b.ID AND 
    a.CUSTOMER_POINTS != b.CUSTOMER_POINTS
```

Both `<>` and `!=` are acceptable "not equals" [operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/non-typed-operators.html).

If you wanted to use `JOIN`s, then you can do:

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM customer_change a
JOIN customer_full b ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.CUSTOMER_POINTS != b.CUSTOMER_POINTS
```

Comment: +1 I'd argue this is the better, more-complete answer at this point (I didn't acknowledge how to only return records from the second table...)